# Is there a cleaner way to reduce this multidimensional byte array to remove duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find a way to remove duplicate entries from a byte array 'byte[][]' returned as a 'new byte[][]'. The code as I have it now seems to work but looks really ugly and I'm wondering if anyone knows any better tricks to improve it. The function I've created looks like this:

```
private byte[][] filterByteArrayValues(final byte[][] values)
{
    final ArrayList<byte[]> listOfBytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    final ArrayList<String> listOfCrc32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (final byte[] value : values)
    {
        final String crc = this.generateCheckSum(value);
        if (!listOfCrc32.contains(crc))
        {
            listOfCrc32.add(crc);
            listOfBytes.add(value);
        }
    }
    final byte[][] output = new byte[listOfBytes.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfBytes.size(); i++)
    {
        output[i] = listOfBytes.get(i);
    }

    return output;

}
```

My biggest regret is how I'm rebuilding the 'byte[][]' for the return value. I'm pretty sure there is a better way, but I can't think of it. Also I'm targeting JRE1.8.

Comment: CRC can yield false positives: lists of different bytes that produce the same checksum.

Comment: hmm.. hadn't thought of that. I'll look into it thanks @biziclop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have confidence in your CRC not to produce false positives, or you are OK with the consequences of eliminating such false positives, another way to do the same thing would be using a `HashMap`:

```
private byte[][] filterByteArrayValues(final byte[][] values) {
    final Map<String,byte[]> res = new HashMap<>();
    for (final byte[] value : values) {
        res.put(generateCheckSum(value), value);
    }
    return res.values().toArray(new byte[res.size()][]);
}
```

The relative order of byte arrays may change, and instead of the first occurrence of the array produced by your code, you would get the last one.

If you do not like reordering, use your method, but replace `ArrayList<String>` with `HashSet<String>` to make your filtering an O(n) instead of the current O(n<sup>2</sup>).

If you do not want false positives, you need to build some infrastructure around a `byte[]` array to make them suitable for use in hash containers:

```
class Mva { // Multi-valued attribute
    private final byte[] data;
    public Mva(byte[] data) { this.data = data; }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // return CRC similar to your generateCheckSum
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // Cast other to Mva, and compare individual values in data[]
    }
}
```

Now you can use [`LinkedHashSet<Mva>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to eliminate duplicates while maintaining the relative order, and without the risk of eliminating false positives.

Comment: Not sure if I can risk the reordering of bytes. The return value eventually makes its way into a Directory Server. These byte arrays are multiple entries in a multi-value attribute.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes, thanks for the ideas. The use of a HashMap, while a little surprising at first, does look like a smooth way of handling the problem.

Comment: Yep that's got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
private byte[][] filterByteArrayValues(final byte[][] values) {

    final Set<Byte[]> set = new HashSet<Byte[]>();

    for (final byte[] value : values) {
        set.add(value);
    }

    return set.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Note how OP uses his `generateCheckSum` method to compare arrays of bytes.

Comment: I'm (naively) assuming that he's using `generateCheckSum` as a way to check equality between `byte[]'s`

Comment: @McN yes that was the idea, but as someone commented under my original question that could introduce a failure as CRC32 could generate false positives. In any case I do plan on reducing the final output if there are duplicates in the original (parameter) array of byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your approach with some optimizations:

```
private byte[][] filterByteArrayValues(final byte[][] values) {
    final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        map.put(generateCheckSum(value), i);
    }
    Integer[] validInexes = map.values().toArray(new Integer[map.size()]);
    byte[][] out = new byte[validInexes.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < validInexes.length; ++i) {
        out[i] = values[validInexes[i]];
    }
    return out;
}
```

But to override `equals` and `hashCode` and just put every value into HashSet seems the better idea.